# loop for Jinj2 flask

Tags: python-3.x, loop, for, flask, jinja2

tenho um loop 'for" no template só que quero que ele mostra uma certa quantidade resultado.

```
{% for form in form %}
    <tr>
       <td><img src="../static/img/arrow-gray.png" alt="">
       <font color="#e3068f"> IGLO{{ form.callsign }}</font></td>
       <td>{{ form.username  }} <b>{{ form.sobrename }}</b></td>
       <td>{{ form.last_seen }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**se eu usor o {{ for form in form }}** ele mostra o resultador

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora se coloco "{{ for form in range(2) }}" que so quero que mostra 2 resultado, ele não mostra nada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem dois errinhos básicos na sua aplicação. O primeiro deles é em relação à nomenclatura das variáveis. No trecho

```
{% for form in form %}
```

você está nomeando a variável que percorre a lista `form` também de `form`. Nesse caso, a maneira correta é dar um nome diferente da lista para o iterador. Um exemplo seria:

```
{% for f in form %}
```

O outro erro é que você quer limitar a dois registros apenas. Nesse caso, você realmente pode iterar sobre a função `range()`, mas agora a lista deverá ser indexada sobre o índice inteiro que você está iterando.

```
{% for f in form %}
    <tr>
       <td><img src="../static/img/arrow-gray.png" alt="">
       <font color="#e3068f"> IGLO{{ f[i].callsign }}</font></td>
       <td>{{ f[i].username  }} <b>{{ f[i].sobrename }}</b></td>
       <td>{{ f[i].last_seen }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Dessa maneira você está limitando corretamente e mostrando o objeto correspondente naquela posição `i` da lista.

Comment: Obrigado funcionou... 

O senhor poder me ajuda eu tenho um banco de dados com vários nomes, queria que me mostrasse somente os 5 últimos registros então eu fiz

{% for i in range(5, 0, -1)  %}
 
só assim me mostra os 5 últimos, queria que me mostrasse o ultimo que registrou no banco de dados

Comment: Opa @DalmoCabral se funcionou pode marcar a resposta como aceita? Sobre esse problema, você tem que alterar a query. Se sua tabela está indexada, pode ordenar os elementos (`ORDER BY`) pelo índice decrescente ou se tiver alguma data de inserção pode ser também. Esse tratamento deve ser feito prioritariamente na query pq fica muito pesado tratar depois no front.